# In Polars, how can you add row numbers within windows?

Tags: python, python-polars

How can I add row numbers within windows in a DataFrame?

This example depicts what I want (in the `counter` column):

```py
>>> df = pl.DataFrame([{'groupings': 'a', 'target_count_over_windows': 1}, {'groupings': 'a', 'target_count_over_windows': 2}, {'groupings': 'a', 'target_count_over_windows': 3}, {'groupings': 'b', 'target_count_over_windows': 1}, {'groupings': 'c', 'target_count_over_windows': 1}, {'groupings': 'c', 'target_count_over_windows': 2}, {'groupings': 'd', 'target_count_over_windows': 1}, {'groupings': 'd', 'target_count_over_windows': 2}, {'groupings': 'd', 'target_count_over_windows': 3}])
>>> df
shape: (9, 2)
┌───────────┬───────────────────────────┐
│ groupings ┆ target_count_over_windows │
│ ---       ┆ ---                       │
│ str       ┆ i64                       │
╞═══════════╪═══════════════════════════╡
│ a         ┆ 1                         │
│ a         ┆ 2                         │
│ a         ┆ 3                         │
│ b         ┆ 1                         │
│ c         ┆ 1                         │
│ c         ┆ 2                         │
│ d         ┆ 1                         │
│ d         ┆ 2                         │
│ d         ┆ 3                         │
└───────────┴───────────────────────────┘
```

Obviously the `df.with_row_numbers()` method exists, but it adds row numbers for the whole dataframe.

Comment: Is group `c` supposed to be `1, 2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate an [`.int_range()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.int_range.html#polars-int-range) over each group with a [window function.](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/window/)

```py
df.with_columns(count = 1 + pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("groupings"))
```

```py
shape: (9, 3)
┌───────────┬───────────────────────────┬───────┐
│ groupings ┆ target_count_over_windows ┆ count │
│ ---       ┆ ---                       ┆ ---   │
│ str       ┆ i64                       ┆ i64   │
╞═══════════╪═══════════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ a         ┆ 1                         ┆ 1     │
│ a         ┆ 2                         ┆ 2     │
│ a         ┆ 3                         ┆ 3     │
│ b         ┆ 1                         ┆ 1     │
│ c         ┆ 1                         ┆ 1     │
│ c         ┆ 1                         ┆ 2     │
│ d         ┆ 1                         ┆ 1     │
│ d         ┆ 2                         ┆ 2     │
│ d         ┆ 3                         ┆ 3     │
└───────────┴───────────────────────────┴───────┘
```